# How to add hourly rows on a daily sequence dataframe?

Tags: r, date, hour

if i have a daily data in the following format:

```
A:
    DD-MM-YYYY
    01-01-2000
    02-01-2000
    03-01-2000
    04-01-2000
    ...
    31-12-2010
    31-12-2010
    31-12-2010
    31-12-2010
```

How to add hourly values to all the days and obtain a new A like:

```
A:
    DD-MM-YYYY hour
    01-01-2000 00:00
    01-01-2000 01:00
    01-01-2000 02:00
    01-01-2000 03:00
    ...
    01-01-2000 21:00
    01-01-2000 22:00
    01-01-2000 23:00

    ...
    ...
    31-12-2010 21:00
    31-12-2010 22:00
    31-12-2010 23:00
```

Comment: `expand.grid(day = A$\`DD-MM-YYYY\`, hour = sprintf("%02d:00", 0:23))`. I assume you don't actually want `24:00`, as it's not a real time. I'm also assuming A is a data frame with a column called `DD-MM-YYYY`, since that's what your question makes it look like.

Comment: Thanks Gregor! I'll try it

Comment: If you want real times, you might do better to use `seq.POSIXt`, it will account correctly for leap years, daylight savings (depending on timezone), etc. My first comment will just stick 24 hours on every day you have.

Comment: If you want, you can comment both as the answer, it would be good to check it as the accepted answer. thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will stick `00:00` to `23:00` on to each of your days:

```
expand.grid(day = A$`DD-MM-YYYY`, hour = sprintf("%02d:00", 0:23))
```

However, in the real world you might prefer to use `seq.POSIXt`, which will account for leap years, daylight savings, etc.